# How to print a Itext Pdf file directly instead of creating a new one

Tags: java

I am trying to create a document using itext 1.3 , i have attached pdftable to the document and now i am trying to print the file instead of downloading the code i am trying to use javax.print funtion but getting error

I had some examples from both stackoverflow and https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=javax.print.SimpleDoc

```
Document document = new Document();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
document.open();
document.add(createFirstTable(this.printData, document));
document.close();
byte[] pdfBytes = baos.toByteArray();
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
PrintService[] pservices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
DocPrintJob job = pservices[0].createPrintJob();
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(pdfBytes, flavor, null);
job.print(doc, null);
```

**Error :**

> [12/27/18 16:44:43:820 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0

in this line

`DocPrintJob job = pservices[0].createPrintJob();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite clear - the list of printservices is empty. You should never access it via an hard index!

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pservices));
//You should never access it via an hard index!
//DocPrintJob job = pservices[0].createPrintJob();

PrintService[] pservices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);
if(!pservices.isEmpty()){
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
  DocPrintJob job = pservices[0].createPrintJob();
  Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(pdfBytes, flavor, null);
  job.print(doc, null);
}
else{
 System.err.println("No printer found.");
}
```

In case you are wondering why there are not printers found, try to not use the `AUTOSENSE` constraint:

```
PrintService[] pservices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, aset);
```